# sql_skip_slave not working in mysql 8.0.30

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-8.0

The Error:

> Worker 1 failed executing transaction '3c852db0-0a3e-11eb-9a41-005056b2f2da:589631974' at master log log_bin_BD6_LDPY.014848, end_log_pos 130823035;
> Could not execute Delete_rows event on table mysql.backup_history;  
> Can't find record in 'backup_history', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log log_bin_BD6_LDPY.014848, end_log_pos 130823035

I tried This command:

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1; 
START SLAVE FOR CHANNEL 'rpl_ldq0_ldpy';
```

And the position as same, it has not changed and the error is not resolved.
How do I solve this?

I tried this command and received the warning:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL SQL_REPLICA_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                              |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 4016 | The value of sql_replica_skip_counter will only take effect for channels running with ASSIGN_GTIDS_TO_ANONYMOUS_TRANSACTIONS <> OFF. |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

More Infos: Replication Master x Master
VERSION: 8.0.30-commercial

Comment: Is `backup_history` your table?  Was there a crash?  Please provide more info on what led up to this situation.